# How to bypass %23 (hash sign) through RewriteRule without data loss?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/command
RewriteRule .* /command/rewritehandler.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI} [B]
```

See specs at currently unanswered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376788/mod-rewrite-directives-and-valid-invalid-utf-8-characters-after-first-character .
If request to server the following `/aaa%23%23aa` then `rewritehandler.php` receives only `/aaa`. Looks like `REQUEST_URI` only handles data before `%23`. What I should type instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture value from `RewriteCond` and then use a back-reference to make it work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule !^command/ /command/rewritehandler.php?q=%1 [NC,B,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This works. All tags except B may be left out, if there is only one `RewriteRule`

Comment: Yes that's true but you never know when someone just comes and add a new rule below this :)