# Redirect on direct file access or rewrite without futher rewrites or redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I want to make working at once:

user requests any request which starts with `/command/rewritehandler.php` and gets redirected to `/`

or user requests anything else that does not starts with `/command/` and this is converted `/command/rewritehandler.php?q=fullpath` if user requested `fullpath`.

```
RewriteEngine On
#Next two lines works with redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/command/rewritehandler\.php
RewriteRule .* /? [L,R]
#Next two lines does expected rewritting without above two lines
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule !^command/ /command/rewritehandler.php?q=%1 [B,L]
```

But after expected rewriting it gets redirected to `/`. How can this be avoided? `L` tag does not prevent another `RewriteRule`s from running here.  Background: [How to bypass %23 (hash sign) through RewriteRule without data loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395719/how-to-bypass-23-hash-sign-through-rewriterule-without-data-loss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable in first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Next two lines works with redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+command/rewritehandler\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* /? [L,R]

#Next two lines does expected rewritting without above two lines
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule !^command/ /command/rewritehandler.php?q=%1 [B,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: If browser sends //command///rewritehandler.php, then this does not work. `\s/+command/+rewritehandler\.php` will work around with this multiple slash issue too.